# object not supported QueryTables.Refresh

Tags: vba, runtime

I am getting the run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property in the following code:

```
           Dim WS1 As Worksheet
           Dim WS2 As Worksheet


          With ThisWorkbook
            Set WS1 = .Worksheets("A")
            Set WS2 = .Worksheets("B")
          End With

          With WS1.ListObjects
              .QueryTables.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 
          End With

         With WS2.ListObjects
            .QueryTables.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
         End With
```

I am at a bit of a loss, where am I going wrong?

Comment: `Refresh` applies to an individual QueryTable, not to a collection. `QueryTable.Refresh` is probably what you need, although you'll have to first identify the ListObject of interest. Or iterate all ListObjects in a Worksheet.

Comment: My bad. I sorted it by:With WSD1.ListObjects(1)
   .QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Answer (score 0):

The `Refresh` method applies to a `QueryTable` object, not to a collection.

If each worksheet only has one ListObject, or it is only the first ListObject (for each worksheet) that is of interest, then:

```
With WS1.ListObjects(1)
    .QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 
End With

With WS2.ListObjects(1)
  .QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

That is, a ListObject only has one QueryTable, that you can Refresh.

---

If worksheets have more than one ListObject then you will need to iterate the collection of them to Refresh each's QueryTable.